# How to add a reference to a child node to another node?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Consider the following format:

```
{
    "events": {
        "one": { ... }
        "two": { ... }
        ...
    }

    "user-events": {
        "foo": {
            "one": true
        }
    }

    "users": {
        "foo": { ... }
    }
}
```

Assuming that I don't know that the name of node `"two"` and it's really some random string, in Firebase, how can add  `"two": true` to `"foo"` in `"user-events"` after the event `"two"` has been made? When I create `"two"`, should I save its generated ID (not actually "two") somewhere in the database?

I ask because I have a feed in a Swift app that contains all of the events from `"events"` and each event cell has a button which is supposed to add the event to the logged-in-user's profile. Under that user's ID (in this case "foo") under `"user-events"`, I would like to add a reference of the event which is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly, you can try do it like this:

1) Generate unicId by `.childByAutoId()` func and save it to your item. For example it will be `post`.

2) Use this `unicId` for saving.

```
static func add(_ postItem: PostItem,
                   completion: @escaping (_ hasFinished: Bool) -> Void) {
    let mainReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "MainDataBase")

    let updates = [
         "/spotpost/" + postItem.key: postItem.toAnyObject(),
         "/spots/" + postItem.spotId + "/posts/" + postItem.key: true,
         "/users/" + postItem.addedByUser + "/posts/" + postItem.key: true
    ]

    mainReference.updateChildValues(updates) 
    { (error, _) in
        if error == nil {
           completion(true)
        } else {
           completion(false)
        }
    }
}
```

You can add it to multiple places at the same time.

Or if you want to add it some time after - you need to store this key in object. Like:

```
+SomeObject
    -key
    -property1
    -...
    -propertyN
```

Then use it.

Hope it helps

Comment: This looks like the initial post. I was wondering: How can I locate a post's key after the post has been made (like you have done)? I would like to add the key to a user's profile.

Comment: @ArchieGertsman "/users/" + postItem.addedByUser + "/posts/" + postItem.key: true. When I m adding new post, I add postId to user posts array.

Comment: Is there any way to call this function without adding the post to the user's post array, and then _later_ add the post to the user's post array? I have two separate buttons: One to create a post to the feed, and another to add a selected post on the feed to the profile.

Comment: @ArchieGertsman amm. Get postItem object. Get Id. What is the problem? reference.key, or, for example, I store key in postItem. I don't understand you atm

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about storing the key inside the postItem. Is that good practice?

Comment: I thought that having "random-string": { "key": "random-string" } looked a little messy but I guess there's nothing wrong with it. Thank you.